# Shed Repair Questions and Guidance

Tags: repair, shed, diy-vs-pro, rot

I've got a bit of a project on my hands, and I'm hoping to tap into the wisdom of this awesome community for some guidance. I've got an 18ft L x 12ft W x 7.5ft H shed that's been around longer than I've owned the property.

While I'm not looking to replace it due to zoning reasons, it's definitely showing its age and needs some serious TLC.

**The Issues:**

- The shed is leaning about 6 to 7 inches towards the left (front-facing).
- The foundation is literally dirt, which has caused the base boards to rot away.
- Wall studs are leaning and unstable due to the deteriorated base boards.

**My Basic Game Plan:**

1. Level and Stabilize: I'm thinking of using a cable/come-along straps attached to trees to gently level the shed horizontally. Then, I'll brace it to ensure it's steady throughout the repair process.
2. Replace Wall Studs: The rotted bottom sections of the wall studs need replacing. I'm hoping that this step will also enhance stability before I proceed to lift the shed for base board replacement.
3. Jack It Up: With proper bracing in place, I'll cautiously jack up the shed about 6-8 inches on all sides.
4. Bottom Plate Replacement: Once elevated, I plan to replace all the rotted base boards.
5. Foundation Upgrade: I'm considering either a gravel or cement foundation for better stability and potential future use as livable space.
6. Set It Down: Lowering the jacks onto the new foundation.
7. Secure Everything: Finally, I'll secure the baseboards firmly to the new foundation.

**My Questions:**

- What would be the best order to tackle these steps while ensuring safety and stability throughout the process?
- I'm concerned about jacking up a potentially unstable shed. Any tips on how to do this safely?
- Should I consider plumbing and electrical work now, in case I want to convert this space into something more functional in the future?

Comment: With no pics, the answer is "it depends."  If it's not safe enough to jack it up for leveling and repair, sounds like it may be a tear-down.

Comment: Rotted bottom plus a lean plus a decent size building.  One mistake can lead to major problems, building falling on you.  I would see if any professionals would want to try to fix it.  If they do not, with their tools/experience, then as a DIY project it might be too much.

Comment: Without photos, I’m guessing that a rebuild is more cost effective than repair. If zoning is a problem, the usual dodge is to do an almost complete rebuild and call it a repair. Some folks will leave a single wall in place. A rebuild would also set you up for possible future plumbing/ electric/ etc.